# Configure center mouse button to open new links

Tags: mouse

I have a simple Logitech mouse with 2 buttons and central wheel button.

The central button opens some accessories (calculator and so on). I would like this button to open new links in chrome (as it does on Windows and Linux). Is there a way to configure that?

I've tried Logitech control center, but it can't find the attached mouse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a feature provided by OSX.

- If you want to open a link in a new tab you <kbd>⌘</kbd>+*click* the link.
- This also works with the *URL-bar* and *search box* using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd>.

Knowing this, you can assign the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+*click* action to the scrolling wheel click using the free software **[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/)**.

I've successfully done this:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. How come this isn't implemented in OSX natively?

Comment: Dunno. Probably because the only apple device that has a middle mouse button is the magic mouse?

Comment: Button 3 used to function as a Command-Click.

Comment: If you cannot configure the click because a gesture (like expose) is overriding the click then go to System pref -> Mission Control and in the lower part (Keyboard and mouse shortcut) make sure to leave a blank ( - ) in the mouse shortcut menu.

Comment: Normal Mouse <3

Answer (score 9):

You *can* set the center mouse button or any other button to open links in a new tab in [Logitech Control Center](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x).

Just change the Assigned action of the "Switch Application Button" or "Center Mouse" button to "Advanced click." Under the "Configure Advanced Click" tab, select "click" under click type and select the "⌘" modifier.

[image: Screenshot here]

Easy Peasy

Comment: Works perfectly, and you don't have to pay for BetterTouchTool